# Dividir fomulário de uma view em tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário de cadastro muito grande, quero dividir ele em Tabs, sendo que o botão de para cadastrar os dados deve ficar na ultima View que contém o formulário

Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Morais, dê um exemplo de um formulário (colocando a view do mesmo), dizendo quais partes você desejaria dividir em abas, facilitará conseguir ajuda. :)

Comment: Por exemplo eu tenho um cliente e quero dividir dados os pessoais do contato, o formulário de dados pessoais seria a primeira tab (primeiro a ser apresentado), o contato seria a segunda tab onde ficaria o botão cadastrar